# UITextField predictive input fails when placeholder is set

Tags: ios, uikit, uitextfield

Setting `UITextField`'s `placeholder` string that contains "search" word and `autocorrectionType` value `.no` breaks predictive input.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var text: String = ""
    var body: some View {
        // Doesn't work.
        TextField("Search", text: $text)
            .disableAutocorrection(true)
        // Works!
        TextField("No Srch", text: $text)
            .disableAutocorrection(true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is only reproducible on iOS simulators. It's verifiable that predictive keyboard works as expected on real devices.

- **iOS Simulators** tested: **15.0**, **15.2**
- **Actual** devices: **15.2**